# ContextMenu position is messed up in Android 7

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-7.0-nougat

I have an app with a simple listview and context menu in it.
pre android 7, everything looks ok:

when clicking an item at the bottom of the list:
[image]

when clicking an item at the top of the list:
[image]

But wit android 7...

when clicking an item at the bottom of the list:
[image]

when clicking an item at the top of the list:
[image]

Was there any change in the position of the context menu?

Comment: Looks like an OS bug. What is the value of "Build number" under Settings > About phone?

Comment: How do you show this context menu? Could you post the code?

Comment: welcome to android!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution for this somewhere (can't remember where).
The problem is between the new context menu and the Holo themes.

**Solution Details:**

I added a style in values-v24 folder that looks like:

```
<resources>

<style name="ContextPopupMenuStyleLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>

<style name="ContextPopupMenuStyleDark" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Common" >
    <item name="android:contextPopupMenuStyle">@style/ContextPopupMenuStyleLight</item>
</style>
```

Then, in my default styles.xml I used a style called

```
AppTheme.Common
```

That defines all my app style, and an empty style called

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Common" />
```

and I used that empty style as the default app style.
This way, on version > 24, the app uses this extra item regarding context menu overlap anchor to fix the issue (bringing context menu to what they looked like before API 24)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone still has the same problem, 
just add this to your theme folder (v14)

```
<item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
```

Comment: I just added this to my style and all worked as it should, thanks for that. I got an error in Android Studio "android:overlapAnchor requires API level 21 (current min is 19)". I didn't want to have to create multiple style folders for every api from 24 upwards. Is it possible to have a resource file that applies to all api's above a certain level?

Comment: current min? you mean minSdkVersion?

Comment: Yes, I meant minSdkVersion. The error doesn't cause any build errors, and the lower level versions don't have the original problem; so it's more of a compulsion I have to not have errors/warnings in my code if possible. The message is a warning in the style resource file in the editor in Android Studio: `android:overlapAnchor requires API level 21 (current min is 16) more... (⌘F1)`.