# Nougat ListView-ContextMenu positioning bug

Tags: android, android-styles

My app suffers from the wrong positioning of the ContextMenue in Anrodi Nougat, see [contextmenu-position-is-messed-up-in-android-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867621/contextmenu-position-is-messed-up-in-android-7) or here [ListView Pop-Up Context Menu broken in Android 7](https://www.mysysadmintips.com/other/programming/758-listview-pop-up-context-menu-broken-in-android-7-api-24)

Unfortunately the suggested solution shows no effect in my app.

I have minSdkVersion="9" and targetSdkVersion="25".

My styles/styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  </style>
</resources>
```

I created this styles-v24/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:contextPopupMenuStyle">@style/myContextPopupMenuStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="myContextPopupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>
```

Unfortunately no effect. Is Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu correct for Theme.Light? I tried to switch to minApi=24 an put the code in styles/styles.xml but in vein. Any ideas what I should try?

There must be a zillion apps with this issue under android 7.

I'm using appcompat-v7:25.1.1 BTW.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out, that of course `AppTheme` must be set in `manifest.xml` as the theme of the app.
I had it set to `Theme.NoTitleBar` a long time ago...